# Probability Density Function given X

Tags: statistics

I have this problem I am unable to solve in my book. It has a provided solution and I am unable to come to this conclusion. The problem is as follows:

Suppose that a random variable X has a PDF given by:

[image: equation]

Find the probability that X <= 1 given X <=1.5

There are other problems previous to this and I got the proper solution by integrating this with respect to X and solving for P's bounds, giving me:

$$ \frac {x^3}{9} $$

However, they want the P(X) <= 1 given P(X) <=1.5. How do I set up the equation? The solution is 0.457

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant 1 | X\leqslant \frac32\right) = \frac{\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant 1\cap X\leqslant\frac32\right)}{\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant \frac32\right)} = \frac{\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)}{\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant \frac32\right)}.$$

Integrating the density function we obtain:

$$\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac13 x^2\mathrm dx = \frac29, $$

$$\mathbb P(X\leqslant \frac32) = \int_{-1}^{\frac32}\frac13 x^2\mathrm dx = \frac{35}{72}.$$

Hence  $$\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant 1 | X\leqslant \frac32\right) =\frac29\cdot\frac{72}{35}=\frac{16}{35}\approx 0.457.$$

Comment: I Am still confused. How do you arrive to the point of 16/35 directly from equation? I see that the part that is obviously the missing link to me is the part with the union.

Comment: That is just the definition of conditional probability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition

Comment: Got it now. Ty so much.